# Generic type swap c function

Tags: c, debugging, heap-memory

I am trying to write a simple function that will swap any two variables of the same of type.

```
void swap(void* a, void* b, int size);

void swap(void* a, void* b, int size){
    void* temp = malloc(size);
    
    memcpy(temp, a,size);
    
    memcpy(a, b, size);
    
    memcpy(b, temp,size);

    free(temp);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char name[] = "name";
    char greet[] = "greet";

    swap(name, greet, 30);

    printf("%s\n", name);
    printf("%s\n", greet);
    
    return 0;
}
```

But what the above code prints is:

```
`
name
```

The value of  pointed to by a (in swap) changes to ` after `memcpy(b, temp, size)`, I am unsure why?

Comment: You can't swap `name` and `greet`, since they have different sizes.  And you certainly can't swap them using a size of 30, since that's much bigger than either of them!

Comment: Going out of bounds will *always* lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: I tested your code on two strings of the same size (passing that size as the third argument to `swap`), and it worked.  So your `swap` function looks okay.

Comment: When rearranging strings, it's usually easier and more efficient to use pointers and rearrange *them*, rather than copying entire string around.

Comment: How should I change my function to have the same definition and work with all types (string, char, float, double, int, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `memcpy(b, temp,size);` with size being equal to 30 and the actual size of the string pointed by `b` being 6, you basically write past the memory you own.

In your case, your program will actually damage the program stack. If in memory `b` comes before `a` the additional 24 will effectively rewrite the contents of `a` completely.

You have to check whether the `size` is less than or equals the least size of the both strings + 1 (to account for the null character).

Comment: How should I change my function to have the same definition and work with all types (string, char, float, double, int, etc)?

Comment: Your function already works with all types. It's just that knowing the size of the arguments isn't the function's job, but the job of the programmer that is going to use the function. It's a general theme in C that functions totally trust the programmer. An example would be `memcpy` function: it totally relies on the fact that _you_ checked that the amount of data you write doesn't exceed the amount you actually _can_ write to the destination. On the contrary `scanf` returns the number of arguments it parsed, since the programmer cannot know, even in theory, if the input will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are some bugs, resulting in undefined behavior.
1. You are copying 30 bytes from an array, which is 5 bytes long ("name" is 4 chars + 1 byte of trailing 0).
2. You are copying 30 bytes to array, which is 6 bytes long ("greet" is 5 chars + 1 byte of trailing 0).
Both bugs can cause the problem, especially the second one: you are trying to use 24 bytes of memory over array bounds - it is not possible to determine the results of this.

As someone wrote in comments, the better way will be exchanging the pointers, nor pointed bytes.

Comment: How should I change my function to have the same definition and work with all types (string, char, float, double, int, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the comments, you cannot swap `greet` and `name`, as their types do not match: `char[6]`, vs `char[5]` (including terminating NUL), and they have different size.

However, the `swap` can be used on char * object, since char array can be converted to char *, the change is simple.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])

    char name[] = "name";
    char greet[] = "greet";

    char *p1 = name ;
    char *p2 = greet ;

    swap(&p1, &p2, sizeof(p1)) ;

    printf("%s\n", p1);
    printf("%s\n", p2);
}
```

Side note: No need to use `malloc` for the temp space, unless you are expecting to move very large objects. Just `char temp[size] ;` will do the work - instead of malloc - and no need to free (and minor performance gain).

Comment: Swap isnt just for strings, it will work with int, float, etc so I cant set temp to char array.

Comment: How should I change my function to have the same definition and work with all types (string, char, float, double, int, etc)?

Comment: @MohamedMoustafa I do not see why any change to 'swap' will be needed, as long as the two arguments have the same type. Which can/type is not working ?